# How come IMGMOUNT works in DOSBox, but displays "cannot create drive from file" in DOSBox variants like DOSBox-X?

Tags: mount, disk-image, floppy, emulation, dosbox

There's a certain file image which can be instantly mounted in DOSBox as a floppy disk, but fails to do so in newer variants like **DOSBox-X**, any idea how to fix it (a bug was already submitted but both got no reply and the same issue seems to occur in all other variants as well)?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. [Download Kryoflux](https://www.kryoflux.com/?page=download) for Windows and extract
2. Enter https://archive.org/details/WWFEuropeanRampageTourOcean199235Kryoflux.7z
3. Download the **Kryoflux Dump** there
4. Use Windows CMD to enter `kryoflux_3.00_windows\dtc\DTC_x64\`
5. Use [KryoFlux COMMAND LINE EXAMPLES](https://github.com/archivistsguidetokryoflux/archivists-guide-to-kryoflux/blob/master/1%20PART%20ONE%20Getting%20Started/1.2%20USING%20THE%20KRYOFLUX/readme.md#command-line-examples) of **Create formatted image files in deviceless mode (i.e., using stream files)** to create a standard IMG file, e.g.

   `dtc -f"WWF European Rampage Tour (Disk 1)(Ocean)(1992)(3,5'')\track00.0.raw" -i0 -fdisk1.img -i4 -m1`

   `dtc -f"WWF European Rampage Tour (Disk 2)(Ocean)(1992)(3,5'')\track00.0.raw" -i0 -fdisk2.img -i4 -m1`
6. Note the second command produces errors:

   `00.0    : Bad sector found`

   `00.0    : Read operation failed`

   `00.1    : Bad sector found`

   `00.1    : Read operation failed`

   `01.0    : Bad sector found`

   `01.0    : Read operation failed`

   `01.1    : Bad sector found`

   `01.1    : Read operation failed`

   `02.0    : Bad sector found`

   `02.0    : Read operation failed`

   `02.1    : Bad sector found`

   `02.1    : Read operation failed`

   `03.0    : Bad sector found`

   `03.0    : Read operation failed`

   `03.1    : Bad sector found`

   `03.1    : Read operation failed`

   `04.0    : Bad sector found`

   `04.0    : Read operation failed`

   `04.1    : Bad sector found`

   `04.1    : Read operation failed`
7. Run `imgmount a disk2.img -t floppy`

**Result in DOSBox**

The file gets mounted successfully.

**Result in DOSBox variants**

Drive A isn't mounted with the message `cannot create drive from file`.

Note it does work perfectly for disk1.